# incrementar linhas com base num registro em postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

Tenho uma consulta que me retorna a quantidade e valor inicial e quero transformar essa consulta em várias linhas conforme a quantidade.

Exemplo:

Consulta:

```
select 3 as numero, 10001 as valorinicial
```

Saída esperada:

```
 id | valor
 ----------

  1. 10001
  2. 10002
  3. 10003
```

Alguma sugestão com *postgresql* ou *postgresql/php*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com a função nativa [generate_series(start, stop, step)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-srf.html)

Para o seu caso

```
Select generate_series(10001 , 10003,1);
```

Veja no funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/23667)

Comment: fantástico, isto mesmo que procurava!